# How easily could a picture password be hacked with brute force?

Tags: passwords, attacks, brute-force, windows-8

In Windows 8.1 Microsoft introduced a method to login using gestures over a picture. The picture password is determined by size, position and direction of any combination of circles, straight lines and taps, and the order in which they're made:
[image: Windows 8.1 picture password]

I assume the software wouldn't expect a **pixel-exact** size, positioning and direction. So a brute force attack could work with some inaccuracy. It's conceivable that a number of, say circles of varying size and position be placed and entered. Sure, the number of combinations would be huge, but it still makes me wonder:

Has any research been done how effective a brute force attack on a picture password would be?

Comment: Without finding out how large errors it accepts, and the details of the detection methods, nobody can tell you how hard/easy it is. ... And if we know, it might be trivial, without any research papers and so on.

Comment: Anyways, I guarantee you that it is a) not as secure as a good password, b) slower to enter, c) larger risk of needing multiple tries to enter it correctly, d) ... in short, the direction that nowadays way too many consumer electronics go: bad for no reason.

Comment: Thanks @deviantfan. Why would it be not as secure as a good password? Is it that someone could easily peek over your shoulder and know the gestures?

Comment: That's one thing, yes. And even from the other direction, arm movements are not invisible. ... Or take https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--0y8JS6s---/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_320/17iu7usrzmmd4jpg.jpg ... Even more important is the limit to three gestures. ...

Comment: Let's assume a 1920x1080 screen, 50 sectors where the finger is recorded (fingers are big on small phones), and a gesture constists of 15 such records. For the first block of a gesture, there are 50 possibilites. For the next, just 8 (up, down, left, right, top-right, and so on). Meaning ca. 6 byte per gesture (not much), 18 for all three. And then think that moving left 2 blocks within one gesture increases the probability that the next block again is left of the previous one, this heuristics reduce the strength again big times. And that humans are no CSPRNGs, again more predictability.

Comment: Thanks, @deviantfan. Ah, makes sense:) Us humans are the biggest obstacles of security.